# How do I count the number of ways to use elements in a list to create a number?

Tags: python, counting

I am a beginner to python and I'm trying to create a program that uses numbers from a list like [1,2,3] to create another list which sums to a specific number. Using the list [1,2,3] as an example, I want to count the number of ways of creating 10 using only those numbers.

The only code I really have is checking whether the list has its sum equal to the number, but I don't totally know where to start from.

Comment: If you can find the common name of this optimisation problem you can probably find an algorithm for it, which will give you a guide as to what the code needs to do. This may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem _"given the available denominations of an infinite set of coins, the objective is to find out the number of possible ways of making a change for a specific amount of money, without considering the order of the coins"_ I think this matches your problem, where the given list represents the "available denominations of an infinite set of coins"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is actually quite tricky considering the logic behind it.
I wrote some code, that solves the task, producing only unique answers.
So for example, if you enter the number from 1 to 9 in order to sum up to 10, it will give the solution `1+4+5` but not `1+5+4` or `4+5+1` and so on. In order to achieve this, you will have to manipulate the code further.

I used a recursive approach. Of course execution time will be quite long for rather large target numbers or available numbers

```
numbers_used = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
target_used = 10

def summation_combination(numbers, target, start_sum=0, start_nums=[]):
    if start_sum == target:
        print(start_nums)
        return
    elif start_sum > target:
        return

    for n, num in enumerate(numbers):
        if n + 1 < len(numbers):
            summation_combination(numbers[n+1:],
                                  target,
                                  start_sum+num,
                                  start_nums=start_nums+[num])

summation_combination(numbers_used, target_used)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 7]
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 8]
[3, 7]
[4, 6]
```

I hope, this is what you expect.